# Angular requesting typed response data with metadata

Tags: angular, rxjs

All responses from my backend (excluding errors) return in this format:

```
{
   "data": [
      ...
   ]
   "meta": { //Always same structure
      "itemsPerPage": 20
      "offset": 0
      "pages": 6554
      "total": 131071
   }
}
```

In angular,
interfaces:

```
export interface user {
   name: string
   id: number
}

export interface meta {
   itemsPerPage: number
   offset: number
   pages: number
   total: number
}
```

Making a request

```
this.http.get<user[]>(...).subscribe(data => {
   this.users = data.data;
   this.meta = data.meta
})
```

How can I set a correct response type here (I am expecting property data of type **user**[] and meta of type **meta**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a generic here so you can reuse the interface.

```
export interface IDataResponse<T> {
    data: Array<T>;
    meta: {
       itemsPerPage: number;
       offset: number;
       pages: number;
       total: number;
    };
}
```

And now specify that in your call.

```
this.http.get<IDataResponse<user>>('url/here')
  .subscribe(response => /* do something with the response */);
```